# Can you keep an excel cell blank unless the neighbouring cells value is above 29?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to make a spreadsheet for marking, the passmark is 30 for one of the tasks and I want to be able to write the mark down in a cell, with the neighbouring cell staying blank unless the value I input is 30 or above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. There are two ways. If the cell in question is a formula, you can simply put that formula in an IF statement:

```
=IF(condition;true;false)
```

In the true field, you would place your original formula, in the false field you would write "" and in the condition field, you would write the check.

Here's an example:

```
=IF(G31>=30;G14+G17;"")
```

If the cell in question is not a formula but only a user input, you can use conditional formatting to paint it white. You can simply write `=G31<30` as formula and apply the color white, meaning: if its not larger than 30, then paint white.